# How to remove "assets" error in pytube in python?

Tags: python, pytube

I had made a **youtube video downloader** using **pytube** in **python**. It previously works fine but during sometime it gives an error of **"assets"**. I had tried a lot but I can't solve it. I had also tried to search error solution but I can't found anything like that.

Here is my code

```
def startDownload(url):
    global file_size
    path_to_save = askdirectory()
    if path_to_save is None:
        return

    try:
            global MaxFileSize, fileSizeInBytes
            choice = youtubeChoicesLabel.get()
            url=urlField.get()
            yt = YouTube(url)
            nome = yt.title
            if (choice == download_choices[1]):
                print("720p video is downloading")
                selectVideo = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first()
                
            elif (choice == download_choices[2]):
                print("144 video is downloading")
                selectVideo = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').last()

                selectVideo = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                
                
            elif (choice == download_choices[0]):
                return

            
                fileSizeInBytes = selectVideo.filesize
                MaxFileSize = fileSizeInBytes/1024000
                MB =str(MaxFileSize)+ "MB"
                print("File Size = : {:00.000f}".format (MaxFileSize))

            st= selectVideo
            yt.register_on_complete_callback(complete_download)
            yt.register_on_progress_callback(progress_download)
            file_size=st.filesize
            st.download(output_path=path_to_save)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

download_choices = ["----Download Type----",
                    "Mp4  720p",
                    "Mp4  144p",
                    # "Video  3gp",
                    "Audio  Mp3"]

def btnClicked():    

    try:
        downloadBtn['text'] = "Please wait....."
        downloadBtn["bg"] = "red"
        downloadBtn["fg"] ="white"
        downloadBtn['state']= 'disabled'
        url=urlField.get()
        if url == '':
            showinfo("Message","Please input a url of the video.....")
            return
        print(url)
        
        thread= Thread(target=startDownload,args=(url,))
        thread.start()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Here is my error

```
soham@LAPTOP-FJLV55TK MINGW64 ~
y"python "e:/python projects/YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py
e:/python projects/YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTuxUAuJRyY
'assets'
```

Comment: You code seems to have some undefined objects. Can you add the details of those, please? It would be preferable if you could include code so that anyone can run it and get the same result, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and updating  `pytube` to the latest version available currently the problem disappeared.

```sh
pip install pytube==10.0.0
```

or

```sh
pip install --upgrade pytube
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492922/pytube-only-works-periodically-keyerror-assets).