# can not download with pytube -> KeyError: 'assets'

Tags: python, pytube

I can not download anything with pytube3, it gives me an Error `KeyError: 'assets'` But I do not know where the problem is ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492922/pytube-only-works-periodically-keyerror-assets):

**Suggestion 1: Install from git**

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue for me.